# in Python turn bracketed, comma delimited string that contains a datetime object into a list

Tags: python-3.x

This looks easy. Maybe it is and I'm not seeing it. How would one turn the following string into a list in Python3?

```
"[(datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 19, 6, 54), '1002', '3.1'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 19, 5, 10), '1001', '1.5')]"
```

I would like a list that looks identical to above without the double quotation marks.

Comment: use `eval(your_string)` of course first you have to `import datetime`

Comment: Where does this string come from?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a legitimate python object:

```
a = "[(datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 19, 6, 54), '1002', '3.1'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 19, 5, 10), '1001', '1.5')]"

import datetime
eval(a)
[(datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 19, 6, 54), '1002', '3.1'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 19, 5, 10), '1001', '1.5')]
```